# Always get parent category name Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just would like to get and display the parent (or grand parent if necessary) category name in WordPress.

I have this :

```
single_cat_title()
```

But it display the actual category name.

My code is in header.php

In this image, in the green part it must be written "Energies Renouvelables"[image]

Have an idea ?

**EDIT**

This is my code, nothing special like I said ..

```
<div class="fil-arianne">
    <?php echo single_cat_title(); //echo get_the_title($parentID);?>
</div>
```

Comment: Try 'echo get_category_parents(get_the_ID());'

Comment: It display just a '/'

Comment: Uh.... Can you please clarify more on what you need with a post-category relation diagram? I think it would be better way to make understand other people.

Comment: Actually I just want to display main category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use `get_category_parents()`. So you would call it like this:

```
get_category_parents( $cat, true, ' &raquo; ' );
```

Which would display something like:

```
The Parent Category » My Category »
```

For the full list of arguments, take a look at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents).

Comment: It's not working for me. It display absolutely nothing

Comment: @Emilien Then you need to show us your code. Because this is a standard WP hook, so it works as is. There must be an issue with your code.

Comment: Ok ! But I can't do it tonight ^^ However my code has nothing special, in a <div> I'm just calling a WP function (like get_the_category_parent())

Comment: Yes I need help ! But the code is at my office .. I'll go tomorrow and I will post it

Comment: Do it when you like. I'm just trying to say that without the code noone can help you.

Comment: In your code you say you are using `single_cat_title()` which is designed to only show the category name of the current post & not the parent / grandparent category.

Comment: Ok, so my question is : How to get parent/grand parent category name ?

Comment: It's there in my answer. That's how you get it. It's a WordPress function. So, if it doesn't work we need to see some more code from you. And a link to the page so we can see the issue working. If it doesn't work then you have some underlying issue breaking this.

Comment: @Emilien Did my answer & comments help you? If so, I'd really appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer to your question. If not, let's see if we can work this out for you.